# Passing props and styles to functional component (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I am struggling to figure out the correct way to use material UI styles and pass props to my functional component.

I have this

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
.....

const styles = {
   media: {
     height: 0,
     paddingTop: '56.25%'
  },
};

const Article = (props, {classes}) => (
<div>
       <Card className="rounded">
            <CardMedia
                className={classes.media}
                image={props.img}
            />
            <CardContent>
                <h3 className="font-weight-bold">{props.heading}</h3>
                <p className="mb-0">
                    {props.description}
                </p>
            </CardContent>
       </Card>
</div>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(Article);
```

I have tried

```
const Article = (props, classes) => (
const Article = ({props, classes}) => (
const Article = ({img, heading, description, classes}) => (
```

it works with just `props` and it works with just `{classes}` but can't get them to work together.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found out that it is passed with the props so I can access it like this.

`const Article = (props) => (`
and
`className={props.classes.media}`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what you found:

You can choose between the prop object or to destruct your props. It looks like this:

```
const Article = ({img, heading, description, classes}) => {
    ...
}
```

That can be a good practise because it is very clear what props are passed down from just reading your component. If you destructure your props you just refer to them without such as:

```
EXAMPLE.function()
```

instead of

```
props.EXAMPLE.function()
```